# while making Http call in asynchronous shows error

Tags: android

During http call it shows error in
HTTPclient ,HttpPost,HttpResponse.
The class did not importing the packages.
And showing to create class when click on error.

Comment: add clarification to your question and show what you have done

Comment: please add Apache library ...  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me Add this dependency to your build.gradle File

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:
```

Answer (score -1):

add dependency in your app module gradle file.

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Hope it helps..